# NSDateFormatter setDateFormat: What's the difference between "DD" and "dd"?

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

Using NSDateFormatter to parse a date. The date below is May 2 2013. I get different results (shown below) depending on whether I use "DD" in the dateFormat string and "dd"

```
NSString * dateStr = @"2013-05-02";
NSDateFormatter * dateFormat =  [NSDateFormatter new];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-DD"];
NSDate * date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
NSLog(@"%@",[dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
//logs 2013-01-02   ** incorrect
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
//logs 2013-05-02   ** correct
```

What is "DD" doing? Does it do anything at all?

I've been looking online to try and find a definitive guide for these date format strings, and I haven't found one yet. If anyone knows of one, please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dd is the day of the month, and DD is the day of the year.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html

That document links to different standards depending on the version of the OS.  The one for iOS 6 is tr35-25: http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns

Comment: Wow, totally looked over that article a bunch of times and just ignored that list completely.